# CakePHP 1.3 - Extract URL GET parameters

Tags: php, url, cakephp, get, cakephp-1.3

I have CakePHP 1.3.2 application working with similar URLs:

```
/controller/action/name1:value1/name2:value2.html
```

I'm trying to extract the values after the `:` sign specified by the names before that. I can see the whole URL with no problem using `$this->params['url']`, however, I can't get the value itself using neither `$this->params['name1']`, nor `$this->params['url']['name1']`. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Cakephp 1.3 book](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#named-parameters):

> URL: /contents/view/chapter:models/section:associations Mapping:
>
> ContentsController->view(); $this->passedArgs['chapter'] = 'models';
>
> $this->passedArgs['section'] = 'associations';
>
> $this->params['named']['chapter'] = 'models';
>
> $this->params['named']['section'] = 'associations';

So you should use:

```
$this->params['named']['name1']
$this->params['named']['name2']
```